# Loading Youtube video in application without WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, youtube

I have many url's like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81_2Xb0XB_E&feature=youtube_gdata

I want to see in my app only the video, rather than a youtube page. 
How can I go about this?
So far I have tried:

```
urlValue = [urlValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"watch?v="
                                             withString:@"v/"];
urlValue = [urlValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&feature"
                                                       withString:@"?version=3&f=playlists&app"];
```

This is the final url :
 https://www.youtube.com/v/81_2Xb0XB_E?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata_player

And this is how I load it:

```
NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"305\" height=\"180\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", urlValue];
```

For some of them it's ok, I can watch it, but for others, like this url I cant watch. ("Watch this video on youtube . Playback on other website has been disabled by the video owner").

Any idea how can I improve my code? or if it's because of url?

Here is an example of url which is working:
 http: //www.youtube.com/v/9M3wwddDec4?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Seems to be related to the settings  of the video provider on YouTube. You need them to allow it to be embedded as far as I can tell.

Comment: yes. you are right . I want to do an app for karaoke and i recceived a feed with urls. Some of them are ok , but for others embeded are not allowed " Embedding disabled by request " . I can do something to solve it ?

Comment: I would think you have to run it in YouTube. I am pretty sure this means running the YouTube app from your app. However that will close your app I think.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser)

Comment: Ideally you should give a code snippet of how the OP might use this project.

Comment: for url with problems it dosnt work . For the others it's ok .

Comment: if you used HCYoutuberParser, try replacing `NSString *signature = nil;` with `NSString *signature = @"";`

Comment: Error. Couldn't find youtube video.